# unable to proceed with dual-boot VHD because windows could not update the computer boot configuration

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, vhd

I've done this before, and everything "just worked" but for some reason setting up a VHD dual boot with Windows 7 this time is stalling.

I create the VHD, no problem
I Install the image form \sources\install.wim no problem
I add an entry to the boot config with bcdedit.

boot the new image and everything looks good.  It goes through the whole adding devices phase and then stops with a dialog box saying:
Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration. Installation cannot proceed"

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very old post I'll assume Ralph solved it, gave up or just had some luck and it "just worked" again.

But for everyone else landing on this question on SuperUser:

> I suggest you follow the approach outlined by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com) on this [blog post here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx).

In particular the section titled 'Install Windows 7 to a new, fresh VHD'

Some key tips that have worked for me in setting up bootable VHDs is to do it via the Windows 7 installation process via the 'repair your computer' option:

1. Use the 'create vdisk', 'select vdisk' and 'attach vdisk' commands
2. Do all your initial bcdedit configuration here
3. Follow the rest of the steps/tips
4. Success